# How to enable the design mode of iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have tried to edit div text which I open in an iFrame like this:

```
$(function() {
    var iframeBody = $("#texteditor").contents().find("body");
    var styleTag = iframeBody.append($('#content'));
    iframeBody.designMode = "on";
})
```

and the page look llike this:

[image: page look llike this]

I am trying to edit the text, but it's not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try instead

```
var iframe = $("#texteditor <iframe-selector>");
var jqIframeBody = $(iframe[0].contentDocument.body);
```

Basically you cannot write a absolute selector starts from your parent window contents, you need to first get into the context (window/document) of iframe and then perform dom operations, or messaging through 1postMessage` however you want.